# There is $\delta$ for which | x | < $\delta$ implies $| f(x)-f(0)| \geq \frac{\lambda |x| }{2}$ if $f'(0)={\lambda}I$ and $f :R^N \longrightarrow R^N$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : R^N \longrightarrow R^N$ is differentiable at the origin and $f'(0) = {\lambda}I$ where I is the identity transformation and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ show that there exists a $\delta$ such that $\forall \lvert x\rvert \lt \delta$ $\implies$  $\lvert f(x)-f(0)\rvert \geq \frac{\lambda\lvert x\rvert}{2}$

I was thinking about using the mean value inequality, but it doesn`t seems to be helpful. I really have no idea of how to begin, can someone give me a clue on what to search for or tag if this question has already been answered? Sorry if it is so elementary, I need some enlightment to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the identity"? Vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ don't have an "identity" element because they are not an algebra

Comment: You cannot use the mean value inequality because you are told $f$ is differentiable only at the origin. Just write down (correctly) the definition of $f’(0)$.

Comment: I edited the title and fixed a typo, in the last expression wanted to mean greater or equal.

Comment: The title is a mess. Don’t put all that in the title. Just say something like “bounding the change in $f$ using its derivative.”

Comment: I think I got it. If f prime is lambda times the identity, then by approaching f(0) in the definition of f prime of zero, there must exist a neighborhood where f(x)-f(0) in absolute value is close as possible to lambda times the identity, and thus is greater than half of lambda. Is this correct?

Comment: Edit your post to include the details, written in precise mathematical terms.

Comment: I think it is more precise now. I think that since f is differentiable and hence continuous, there must exist a delta such that the quotient is arbitrarly close to lambda times de identity, since it is his derivative at zero.
@TedShifrin

Comment: Start with the actual limit definition of the multivariable derivative and use the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of limit.